# Passagem de parametro objeto Drawable

Tags: java, android

Criei um método para encapsular uma mensagem de notificação (`Notification.Builder`). Um trecho do código é apresentado abaixo:

```
 public void exibirMensagem(String titulo, String texto,Drawable icone)
{
    Notification.Builder mensagem = new Notification.Builder(contexto)
             //TROCAR PARA O ÍCONE PADRÃO DA APLICACAO
            .setSmallIcon(icone);}
```

Acontece que o método `.setSmallIcone` não aceita o objeto icone que foi passado por parametro. **icone fica sublinhado em vermellho** e quando passo o curso do mouse aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> Cannot resolved method
>   'setSmallIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Como posso resolver isto, ou seja passar um Drawable como parametro e usar no método `setSmallIcon`?

Comment: Você deve passar int do ícone por parâmetro. Exemplo: `exibirMensagem(String titulo, String texto,int icone)`. Ai você faz desta forma: `exibirMensagem("Titulo", "Conteudo",R.drawable.meu_icone)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com a [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html), o parâmetro que deve ser passado para o setSmallICon é um `Int` ao invés de uma `Drawable`.

Então o seu código deveria ser assim:

```
public void exibirMensagem(String titulo, String texto, int icone)
{
    Notification.Builder mensagem = new Notification.Builder(contexto)
         //TROCAR PARA O ÍCONE PADRÃO DA APLICACAO
        .setSmallIcon(icone);
}
```

> Como usar o código acima?

```
// FloatingActionButton -> OnClickListener...
exibirMensagem("hello world", "Hello world is so nice, guys!", R.drawable.ic_hello_app);
```

Comment: Foi exatamente isso que eu disse. huehueBr

Comment: Não copiei da sua resposta, muito menos viu seu comentário. Apenas postei a minha. Abri a documentação e vi os parâmetros que a função pede e mostrei o caminho pro usuário. Antes de achar que tô copiando das tuas respostas, dê uma olhada nas suas. Quase todas são baseadas em respostas de outras perguntas, a maioria são pura cópia. Abç.

Comment: Eu não falei que vc estava errado, eu disse que foi exatamente oque eu disse. Vou até te dar um +1 por ser uma resposta valida